# Why Phillips-Perron test returns "singularities in regression"?

Tags: r

I'm doing an unit root test using **Phillips-Perron** in the *tseries* library (pp.test).

I tried this code:

```
> pp.test(c(1:1000))
```

and the result is:

```
Error in pp.test(c(1:1000)) : Singularities in regression
```

doing a research I found the lines on the pp.test function with this error:

```
if (res$rank < 3)
   stop ("singularities in regression")
```

*where **res** is the linear model (lm).*

Why i get this kind of error?

If I do the same thing with another unit root test (in the same library) like ADF I don't get errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get this error because the model matrix in the linear model is exactly [colinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) (i.e., one of the predictor variables can be written as linear combination of the other predictor variables). If you add some noise to the time-series, then your example will run:

```
> pp.test(jitter(1:1000))

        Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  jitter(1:1000)
Dickey-Fuller Z(alpha) = -1083,254, Truncation lag parameter = 7,
p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In pp.test(jitter(1:1000)) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
```